# Hide bookmarks bar on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, bookmarks

I am using iPad and the bookmarks bar takes up too much space on screen. I want to remove but cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

**Settings** → **Safari** → disable **Show Favorites Bar**.